# Not show data from database Codeignter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

The database table "tb_bills" is populated but the table returns no data.
And error is shown either. What could be the issue? what am I missing?
Please check the code below, of the view, the model and the controller.

The table view.

```
<tbody>

<?php if(!empty($tb_bills)): ?>
<?php foreach($tb_bills as $bill): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $bill['bill_No'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bill['bill_Title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bill['bill_Type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bill['committee'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $bill['bill_sponsor'];?></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</tbody>
```

The model

```
class RegisterModel extends Model{

    protected $table = 'tb_bills';

    protected $primaryKey = 'bill_Id';
    
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'bill_No',
        'bill_Title',
        'bill_Type',
        'bill_Object',
        'in_Capacity',
        'bill_Sponsor',
        'parliament',
        'no_Clauses',
        'session',
        'committee',
        'bill_Document',
        'added_DateTime',
        'updated_DateTime'
    ];

}
```

The controller

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

```
public function index(){
    $registerModal = new RegisterModal();
    $data['bills'] = $registerModal->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll();
    return view('register-bill', $data);
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
<?php foreach($bills as $bill): ?>
```

in your view

Comment: That looks like the answer to me as well, he's exporting 'bills' to the view.

Comment: Well it still won't work.

Comment: @avrazor It shown an error, right? I would like to know what exactly it said.
As for the controller, $data['bills'] = $registerModal->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll();
I think you should change it to $data['bills'] = $registerModal->orderBy('bill_id', 'DESC')->findAll();

Comment: @Hesse, it only shows the table headings without the data. I commented out  <?php //if(!empty($bills)): ?> and it gave me an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

try to insert a function in your model

```
public function getUsers()
{
   return $this->findAll();
}
```

and then try this for your controller

```
$$registerModal = new RegisterModal();
$data['bills'] = $$registerModal->getUsers();
```